# Global Function in SailsJs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sails.js, ejs

I have created a function, which contains some configuration for a partial.

I want to call this this function in my xy-view.page.js. I tried to create a helper, because in the docs they wrote

> Helpers can be called from almost anywhere in your code; as long as that place has access to the sails app instance.

But in my xy-view.page.js I have no sails instance so i cant write `this.sails.helpers.MyHelper(x,y,z);`


Is there an alternative, so I can use this function in multiple .page.js?

Comment: An alternative approach: Sails 1.x recommends using [helpers](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers) as opposed to services for the same functionality - have you tried using those as well?

Comment: The services are not documented in v1.0, so helpers recommended. @johnabrams7 is it right, if i say helpers are only for backend code? If they are for the frontend code, then i have no idea how to access them, because i have no acces to the sails variable (its only in scope of the api folder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Helpers` are for backend code, they help you share code between different actions and helpers.  In frontend code, you can do the same thing with "utilities" as defined by Parasails - for more info: check out the [Sails.JS Platzi](https://courses.platzi.com/courses/sails-js/) course and have a peak at the `assets/js/utilities` folder in your app.